# Usage of SPNEGO in C++ application to acquire Kerberos ticket

Tags: c++, kerberos, spnego, gssapi

I did an C++ application which supposes to use Kerberos authentication to access HDFS.
This application has webserver written on C++ as well.

I'm trying to make transparent authentication in this application with Kerberos ticket.

I made my server response to unauthorized user with:

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>
> WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate

The browser reacts with an Authorization field in the header which is looks like this:

> Authorization: Negotiate YIIECgYGKwYBBQUCoIID/jCCA/qgCjAIBg...

At this point I got confused about further negotiation with browser to get a proper Kerberos ticket from it.

As I understand I have to use GSSAPI from kerberos5 library to process this Negotiation to acquire the ticket. But I have no idea how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect mod_auth_gssapi or use a ready to go web server like Apache Web Server.